# Need info in getting the date from filename in logstash

Tags: logstash-configuration

currently i have filename with the below format
[XXXXXXXX][YYYYYYYYYY][2016_07_21][19_21_12][160721T192103][ZZZZ]AB_RTRT.0.log.
is there a way, i can extract the datetimestamp and index it to a specific field in elastic search.

thanks
Subbu